# To List All invalid datetime formats in a table in SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using a table to Store Orders in which i used a column with datatype varchar to store date time values. After Longtime i encountered a problem while i made a query to cast the varchar value to datetime then I get a ERROR like this....

Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Now I need to get all the records that raise the above error.
Give me a solution to get all records in temptable..

Thanks in Advance.........

Comment: Please note how this site works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/27535

Answer (score 1):

[ISDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx)